# MVC EXT.NET Передача параметра

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, controller

во вьюхе есть некоторая кнопка с деректИвентом вызывающим метод контроллера. В обычном случае я бы передавал туда параметр таким образом

```
de.Click.ExtraParams.Add(new StoreParameter("filter", "Ext.encode(App.fpFilterMiddleData.getForm().getFieldValues(true))", ParameterMode.Raw));
```

Но в данном случае у меня есть объект шарповской модели, и хотелось бы:

```
de.Click.ExtraParams.Add(new StoreParameter("filter", @Model, ParameterMode.Raw));
```

Но в параметре требуется тип string, как это реализовать (Модель - элемент списка в котором несколько параметров)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот я молодец, не додумался посмотреть определения, ответ очевиден:

```
de.Click.ExtraParams.Add(new StoreParameter("filter", Model));
```